# bootstrap tooltip not styled

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am using the Bootstrap tooltip, however, it appears unstyled. How can I get the styled version shown in the Bootstrap documentation?

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span12 pagination-centered">
     <div class="btn-group">
       <a href="who.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-xlarge" data-toggle= "tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="stuff?">WHO</a>
       <a href="what.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-xlarge" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="more stuff?">WHAT</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. It appears the error is elsewhere, most likely where you specify your stylesheets.

Here's a working fiddle using your exact code:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xjz7wbb/1/)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12 pagination-centered">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a href="who.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-xlarge" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="stuff?">WHO</a>
      <a href="what.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-xlarge" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="more stuff?">WHAT</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Are you sure you're including the Bootstrap stylesheet?

Comment: I have this at the top of my code:     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Can you add a forward slash before the css part?  Try "/css/bootstrap.min.css".

Comment: still no luck - could something in my css be overriding?

Comment: It's possible, unfortunately without seeing more of your code it's hard to say.  Can you try viewing the source of your page and clicking on the css/bootstrap.min.css link?  Does it actually load a stylesheet or just give a 404 not found error?  Are the rest of your elements on the page styled correctly or is nothing being styled like Bootstrap?

Comment: oh wait - for some reason, the bootstrap css file didn't even show up in under sources in chrome developer tools...Is this the problem? Is Bootstrap not properly installed?

Comment: It looks like it's not getting loaded, which could be due to a typo, a tag not being closed properly, etc.  Can you copy and paste the entire <head> tag here?  If it's very large, can you copy and paste at least a few lines before and after the bootstrap CSS file (including that line as well)?

Comment: ah! it was an issue with the <head> tag. thanks so much, michael!